How to populate data into a column in a SQL table where there are duplicate entries from another table?
Table_1 looks like this:



full_name
user_id
random_column_1




John Smith
1234
blah


Joe Smith
5678
blah


Jane Doe
5978
blah


Mark Long
5971
blah



Table_2 looks like this:



user
user_id
random_column_2




Jane Doe

blah


Jane Doe

blah


Mark Long

blah


Mark long

blah



What I want to do is populate the user_id column in Table_2 based on the user_id in Table_1.
Both of these tables have additional columns that I don't want to modify in any way.
I am running this query:
UPDATE Table_2
SET user_id = (SELECT user_id 
               FROM Table_1 
               WHERE Table_2.user = Table_1.user_id;

But I am getting this error message:

Single-row subquery returns more than one row

I know this is because there are duplicate entries for users in Table_2. It's not an option to de-duplicate the users in Table_2.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

user_id from Table_1 does not correspond at all to user from Table_2. I would suggest to provide more realistic example

Updated with a more realistic example.

Why do you want to copy data between tables? Redundancy leads to inconsistency. Consider a view instead.

update T
set T.user_id=X.user_id
from Table_2 as T
join
(
   select full_name,max(user_id)as user_id
   from table_1
   group by full_name
)as x on T.user=x.full_name

This syntax is valid for MS SQL Server. Something similar can be written also for PostgreSQL
or you can also use MERGE
MERGE INTO TABLE_2 AS TGT
USING
(
  select full_name,max(user_id)as user_id
   from table_1
   group by full_name
)AS SRC 
ON TGT.user=SRC.full_name
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  TGT.User_id=SRC.USER_ID


considering that there is some matching value in user and full_name dataset,
UPDATE Table_2 t2
JOIN Table_1 t1
ON t2.user = t1.full_name
SET t2.user_id = t1.user_id;


Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let OP and other readers know which dbms this is for.
